# Java 9: Find Exception, Unable to derive module descriptor for, with elasticsearch-7.3.2.jar

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-9, java-module

Trying to use java 9 modules with a project, I have the following error by building with Intellij:

```
Information:java: java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/laurentthiebaud/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.3.2/elasticsearch-7.3.2.jar
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:647)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readModule(ModulePath.java:330)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scan(ModulePath.java:236)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.scanNextEntry(ModulePath.java:189)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.findAll(ModulePath.java:165)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findAll(Resolver.java:842)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.bind(Resolver.java:223)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:482)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:288)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getServiceLoader(JavacFileManager.java:985)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain$2.invoke(JavacMain.java:290)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorLoader(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:261)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:237)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:193)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1136)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:195)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:460)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:330)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:255)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:213)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1324)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1004)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1071)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:965)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:794)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:376)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:288)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:121)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Information:java: Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.document.Completion50PostingsFormat not in module
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.deriveModuleDescriptor(ModulePath.java:554)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.module.ModulePath.readJar(ModulePath.java:643)
```

In my pom.xml I have indeed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

(7.3.2 is the latest version).

In my module-info I have also:

```
requires elasticsearch;
```

Now when I build with Maven I git quite the same:

```
Can't extract module name from elasticsearch-7.3.2.jar: Provider class org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.document.Completion50PostingsFormat not in module
```

Is it because of elastic being not java 9 compatible (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/38299)? Shouldn't I use modules because of it, or is there any workaround?

Comment: The error faced because of an underlying transitive maven dependency `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-7.3.2`. More thoroughly explained in [this comment on github](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28984#issuecomment-373322067) and further references to work for [some errors similar to this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/38192)

Comment: The error suggests that the JAR file contains a services configuration file in META-INF/services that provides an implementation that is missing from the JAR file. This suggests there could be problems even if you deploy it on the class path. Best to follow up with the elasticsearch project.